# What is the "when expression" of panel view focused

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to bind the `ctrl+l` keyboard keys to the `clear console` command when the panel is focused, but I can't figure out which of the `when expression` might help me achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction",
    "when": "panelFocus"
  }
```

You will get intellisense for "most" context keys in the when clause when your cursor is at the pipe character below:

`"when": "|"`

then typing `panel` brings up a few options, `panelFocus` appears to work.

Some context keys are here: [when clause context documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts).

The most complete method to find all available context keys is to use the [inspect context keys utility](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#inspect-context-keys-utility).

Comment: that "intellisense" helped me thx